# Checking if first character of each word is Uppercase

Tags: regex, uppercase, lowercase

I would like to check if the first character of each word of a string is uppercase.
Other characters should be lowercase.

For Example:

```
My Lady D'Arbanville => True
My Lady d'arbanville => False
My LADY D'Arbanville => False
```

I tried : `^[A-Z][a-z ']*$`
but not working

Comment: `^` matches the beginning of the string, not the beginning of a word.

Comment: Use `\b` to match a word boundary.

Comment: How do you define a "word"?

Answer (score 5):

If there can be a single quote between 2 uppercase chars, you can optionally repeat that.

```
^[A-Z](?:'[A-Z])*[a-z]+(?: [A-Z](?:'[A-Z])*[a-z]+)*$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `[A-Z]` Match a char in the range A-Z
- `(?:'[A-Z])*` Optionally repeat `'` and a char A-Z
- `[a-z]+` Match 1+ lowercase chars in range a-z
- `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole

  - `[A-Z]` Match an uppercase char
  - `(?:'[A-Z])*` Optionally repeat `'` and an uppercase char
  - `[a-z]+` Match 1+ chars in range a-z
- `)*` Optonally repeat the non capture group preceded by a space
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YJQBPp/1)

To also match a single uppercase char:

```
^[A-Z](?:'[A-Z])*[a-z]*(?: [A-Z](?:'[A-Z])*[a-z]*)*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/x84RLo/1)

Comment: Hello, it doesn't seem to match if there is no quote or just a character.  Ex: Once Upon A Time (0 Match)

Comment: @RyanDavidson then you can change the quantifier from `+` to `*` like `^[A-Z](?:'[A-Z])*[a-z]+(?: [A-Z](?:'[A-Z])*[a-z]*)*$` See https://regex101.com/r/oNNHSY/1

Comment: It's a good answer but this does not handle the case of "City B".

Comment: @wlwl2 If you need that, you can update the pattern like `^[A-Z](?:'[A-Z])*[a-z]+(?: [A-Z](?:'[A-Z])*[a-z]*)*$` https://regex101.com/r/u1XPlc/1

Answer (score 4):

With your shown samples, please try following regex.

```
^[A-Z][a-z]+\s+[A-Z][a-z]+\s+[A-Z](?:'[A-Z])?[a-z]+$
```

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/YlgZSN/1)

***Explanation:***  Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
^[A-Z][a-z]+      ##Checking from starting of value if it starts from capital letter followed by 1 or more small letters here.
\s+               ##Matching 1 or more space occurrences here.
[A-Z][a-z]+       ##Matching 1 occurrence of capital letter followed by 1 or more small letters here.
\s+               ##Matching 1 or more space occurrences here.
[A-Z](?:'[A-Z])?  ##Matching single capital letter followed by optional ' capital letter here.
[a-z]+$           ##Matching 1 or more occurrences of small letters till end of value here.
```

Answer (score 1):

I hate relying entirely on regex, it's hard to isolate edge cases or narrow down generalities. Although OP's question asks for a regex to an objective, there's simpler ways to meet this objective and leave room to adapt.

The function below will pass a `string` (ex. `"My Lady D'Arbanville"`) then:

1. `.split()` the `string` into an *`array of strings`* by removing a whitespace (`\s`) OR (`|`) a single quote (`'`).

   ```
    `My Lady D'Arbanville`.split(/\s|'/);
   ```

   returns: `["My", "Lady", "D", "Arbanville"]`
2. `.every()` *word* in the *`array of strings`* will be tested by a `function()`. Each tested *word* must be `true` in order to report the given `string` as `true`.

   ```
    ["My", "Lady", "D", "Arbanville"].every(function(word) {})
   ```
3. The `function()` will `.test()` each *word* to see if the following are `true`:

   - the first character is an upper case letter `[A-Z]`
   - all characters following the first character are lower case `[a-z]+`

   OR `|`

   - the `\b`*word*`\b` is a single character that is a letter in upper case `[A-Z]`

   ```
   /[A-Z][a-z]+|\b[A-Z]\b/.test(word)
   ```

```js
const titleCheck = (text) => {
  const wordArray = text.split(/\s|'/);
  console.log(wordArray);
  return wordArray.every(word => {
    const rgx = new RegExp(/[A-Z][a-z]+|\b[A-Z]\b/);
    return rgx.test(word);
  });
};

/* true
Control 
*/
console.log(titleCheck(`My Lady D'Arbanville`));

/* false
A word starting with a lower case letter
*/
console.log(titleCheck(`My Lady D'arbanville`));

/* false
A word with any upper case letter that is
NOT the first letter
*/
console.log(titleCheck(`My LADY D'Arbanville`));

/* false
A single letter word that is lower case
*/
console.log(titleCheck(`My Lady d'Arbanville`));
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking the negative condition is from far more simple:

```
\b[a-z]|\B[A-Z]
```

if this pattern succeeds, the condition is false.